# sqlite3 is changing values of column when query

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database looks like this:
[image]

When i make simply query: `SELECT 2019, Code FROM maps`
It's changes the values of 2019 column. Output look like this:
[image]

How can i avoid this?
Should i rename column names?
Cheers

Comment: I dont see the problem, what is changed?

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the column name of digits or reserved keywords as a string:
`SELECT "2019", Code FROM Maps`

If you pass just integer `2019` that will be assignment and not a column name. :)